# Kazam main window not showing

Tags: window, python3, kazam

I'm running ubuntu 16.10.  Kazam worked fine until yesterday, when suddenly the main window stopped showing up.

I've tried a lot of things, including reinstalling. Now it's showing, but entirely blank.  I can get it to work by right-clicking Kazam on the launcher, and selecting Preferences, which kills Kazam, and then opening it a second time.

Per a comment below, I tried calling kazam from the terminal, and I get this:

> $kazam 
>   /usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without
>   specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
>   before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.   from
>   gi.repository import Gtk
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/webcam.py:24:
>   PyGIWarning: GUdev was imported without specifying a version first.
>   Use gi.require_version('GUdev', '1.0') before import to ensure that
>   the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import GObject,
>   GUdev /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/gstreamer.py:35:
>   PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use
>   gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the
>   right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import GObject, Gst,
>   GstVideo /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/gstreamer.py:35:
>   PyGIWarning: GstVideo was imported without specifying a version first.
>   Use gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0') before import to ensure that
>   the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import GObject,
>   Gst, GstVideo
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/window_area.py:29:
>   PyGIWarning: Wnck was imported without specifying a version first. Use
>   gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0') before import to ensure that the
>   right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject,
>   Gdk, Wnck, GdkX11
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/indicator.py:149:
>   PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version
>   first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to
>   ensure that the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import
>   AppIndicator3
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/window_countdown.py:29:
>   PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version
>   first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to
>   ensure that the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import
>   Gtk, GObject, GLib, Gdk, Pango, PangoCairo
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/indicator.py:98:
>   PyGIWarning: Keybinder was imported without specifying a version
>   first. Use gi.require_version('Keybinder', '3.0') before import to
>   ensure that the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import
>   Keybinder
>
> ** (kazam:15089): WARNING **: Binding 'W' failed! WARNING Main - No Xlib support in python3, unable to capture key and mouse
>   clicks. /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py:168: Warning:
>   value "((GtkIconSize) 32)" of type 'GtkIconSize' is invalid or out of
>   range for property 'icon-size' of type 'GtkIconSize'
>   self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(prefs.datadir, "ui",
>   "kazam.ui"))
>
> (kazam:15089): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has
>   a parent
>
> (kazam:15089): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has
>   a parent

Do I have a problem with my Python version or configuration?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how your kazam window looks like and can you start kazam from the terminal and provide the output? Maybe there is a hint in there.

Comment: Sethos II: thanks, the idea of running from the terminal was great.  It does give a lot of warnings.  Unfortunately, I don't quite understand them yet!  The screenshot doesn't seem to me to show much--it's either all there or not at all...

Comment: I compared your output with the output of my (working) Kazam. The differences are the warning from `gstreamer.py` and `window_countdown.py` and most notably `** (kazam:15089): WARNING **: Binding 'W' failed! WARNING Main - No Xlib support in python3, unable to capture key and mouse clicks.` Do you have `python-xlib` and `python3-xlib` installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: I just needed to install python3-xlib:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-xlib
```

(Big thanks to Sethos II above!!)