# Kazam - WARNING Kazam - Failed to correctly detect operating system

Tags: package-management, python, python3, kazam

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04LTS 
`python --version`: Command python not found 
`python3 --version`: Python 3.8.2

Kazam was working well. I regularly upgrade packages using `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` commands. I also update OS using `update-manager -c` command. So, one day kazam has stopped working. It gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING Kazam - Failed to correctly detect operating system.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/kazam", line 147, in <module>
    from kazam.app import KazamApp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py", line 36, in <module>
    from kazam.backend.prefs import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 30, in <module>
    from kazam.backend.webcam import Webcam
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/webcam.py", line 24, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject, GUdev
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 132, in load_module
    raise ImportError('cannot import name %s, '
ImportError: cannot import name GUdev, introspection typelib not found
```

I had run `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` for a different purpose. After some days the following happened: (Don't know how the system installed this python version) 
`python --version`: Python 2.7.18rc1 
Later I deleted the symbolic link too. So, now `python` command outputs Command not found.

Comment: I have the same problem. I followed possible solutions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/908620/kazam-main-window-not-showing and https://askubuntu.com/questions/982233/kazam-fails-with-pygiwarning-gtk-was-imported-without-specifying-a-version-fir but neither helped.

Comment: I also tried. Didn't work for me too.

Answer (score 1):

The errors aren't that serious but the fact that Kazam isn't working is. To start, first ignore the errors, then try this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge kazam
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Then if sound isn't working follow this post:

[Screen recording applications are not detecting audio in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234314/screen-recording-applications-are-not-detecting-audio-in-ubuntu-20-04)

The problem with Kazam is it's open source software and the last time the source was updated is 2 years ago. So fiddling required.

Answer (score 0):

I removed .confg for Kazam and it solved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228559)