# Screen recording applications are not detecting audio in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio, update-manager, 20.04, audio-recording, kazam

Two days back I upgraded ubuntu 19.04 into 20.04 lts. However, I noticed that the update got stuck at a particular stage saying 'Removing gnome-logs snap'. This window stays forever

Screenshot of the error while updating:

[image: screenshot of the error while updating]

And the screen recording application Kazam is not recording audio. I tried with different screen recorders but of no use. No application detects the microphone. I looked for any changes in settings but everything was fine. I could see microphone detecting the sound from the dynamic bars. While trying to open it in terminal it shows this error

```
$ kazam
WARNING Kazam - Failed to correctly detect operating system
```

It was showing kazam failed to detect audio recording device few hours back. I uninstalled and reinstalled the application but nothing worked. I even installed PulseAudio volume controller but it neither detects any application that uses audio recording option.

Screenshot of PulseAudio volume controller detecting no recording device:

[image: Screenshot of PulseAudio volume controller detecting no recording device]

However, the Telegram desktop client is perfectly recording audio. I don't know what exactly happened with these applications.

This is the screenshot of Kazam not detecting the recording device:

[image: This is the screenshot of Kazam not detecting the recording device]

I want to make a lecture video for my students but I'm stuck with these issues for hours. I would have changed the OS altogether. But since I don't have a USB I can't try that option. Somebody please answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is due the use of a deprecated python feature. This [PR](https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/pull/40) fixes it, so this should be OK if Kazam ever gets updated again.

Anyways, to fix your problem, as I commented [here](https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/issues/39#issuecomment-622652104) using that PR, you can run

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.py
```

And replace its content with this [content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hzbd/kazam/aca8dd4e2eb9caf676682933a06bc997decd5804/kazam/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.py).

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Worked perfectly well within seconds. I have been scratching my head over it for over 6 hours straight.. You saved my life.. Again, Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. For me, it also solves the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. Worked for me.