# How can I record sound from both speakers and microphone in Kazam?

Tags: sound, audio-recording, pavucontrol, kazam

I am doing online demos and webinars and use Kazam to record them. How can I record both the sound from the speakers (videos I play or what the webinar attendees are saying) and microphone (what I say during the webinar) at the same time?

The way I do it currently is by setting up Kazam to record both the monitor of my headset and the builtin speakers by using `pavucontrol`, but sometimes it does not work, for yet unknown to me reasons (intermittently???) the sound from speakers is not recorded.

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

My recording setup: [image: pavucontrol Kazam recording setup]

My Kazam setup: [image: Kazam setup]

Comment: Did you tick both sound from speakers and sound from mic? Can you also add you Kazam configurations? And what is your setup?

Comment: @rvcabc Yes I did choose to record both speakers and mic. I have attached the Kazam screenshot. Which other configurations should I share?

Comment: have you tried this[1]?

[1] https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/issues/39#issuecomment-622652104

Comment: Also, I found this question on ask ubuntu that might apply. I know both are labeled Ubuntu 20.04, but the fix might work for 16.04. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234314/screen-recording-applications-are-not-detecting-audio-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Also, is there a a Monitor of built-in Audio Analog stereo option as described in this article. https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_linux.html

I know Im sending these one after the other and I apologize if it's a bit overwhelming.