# Kazam - not recognising headset though pulseaudio.py is up-to-date, it uses time.perf_counter()

Tags: 20.04, sound, headset, audio-recording, kazam

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Kazam doesn't detect the headset:

[image]

If I check the sound device in the menu-bar in Ubuntu, it is shown that the headset is connected

[image]

I have been reading in askubuntu.com about similar issues and many of them refer to a change in the pulseaudio.py file (e.g. [Screen recording applications are not detecting audio in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234314/screen-recording-applications-are-not-detecting-audio-in-ubuntu-20-04) and also https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/pull/40)

I have checked the file pulseaudio.py in my ubuntu, and it is as it should be, it uses time.perf_counter().

I don't know what else I should check. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here. Ubuntu 18.04. Only builtin audio is recognized.